# The set of entire function follow the condition ${|f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

let

> $$F= \left \{f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \;\;|f \;\;\text{where f is entire function} \right   \}\\ \text{such that }{|f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|} \;\;\; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}   $$

Then

> 1). $F$ is an infinite set.
>
> 2). $F=\left \{\beta e^{\alpha z}:\beta \in \mathbb{C},|\alpha| \leq 1 \right \}$

The solution I Tried-

As we know that if $f$ s entire then its derivative is also entre so $f'(z)$ is also entire ,now according to question it is given that $$|f'(z) \leq |f(z)|$$ so it implies that $$\frac{|f'(z)|}{ |f(z)|} \leq 1\;\; \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$but as we know that denominator should not be zero for fraction to be exist thus $f(z)$ should't be zero for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ $\Rightarrow$ function $f$ should be of the form $e^{\alpha z}$ because exponential function doesn't have zero in complex Plane.Next I am not getting how to proceed .

Please help!

Comment: Are you claiming $f(z) = 0$ is not an entire function?  I note that for this function $|f'(z)| \leq |f(z)|$...

Comment: hmmm, i don,t think about it lol, but still this answer will take us no where.

Comment: If $f(z) = 0$, then $|f'(z)|\le 0$ and so $f'(z) = 0$.

Comment: yes you are correct but how will you prove that two options.

Comment: leave the trivial case.

Comment: You write "denominator should not be zero for fraction to be exist", but you are shown a function giving you a denominator equal to zero for an obvious entire function.  Perhaps you should re-examine your thoughts on zeroes of $f$.  Also, the indeterminant form $\frac{0}{0}$ should be familiar to you.

Comment: This means that my solution is wrong?

Comment: @gauravsaini Yes, of course. You divide eventually by zero and claim that an entire function that has no zeros must be an exponential.

Comment: okk will work on it.

Comment: Your first aim should be to prove that $f' = \alpha f$ for some $\alpha$. If $f$ does not have any zeros, then $f'/f$ is entire and bounded and hence a constant, i.e., $f' = \alpha f$. If $f$ has a zero in $z_0$, could it possibly be true that $f'/f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part is easy because all constant functions are in $F$.

For the second part, here is a proof.

The zero function is of the form $\beta e^{\alpha z}$ with $\beta=0$.

If $f$ is not the zero function, fix $z_0 \in \mathbb C$. Write $f(z)=(z-z_0)^m g(z)$, where $g(z_0)\ne0$ and $m\ge 0$.

If $m\ge 1$, then $|f'(z) \leq |f(z)|$ at $z=z_0$ gives $|mg(z_0)|=0$, a contradiction.

Thus, $f$ has no zeros. By Liouville's theorem $f'/f$ is a constant function, and so $f'(z)=\alpha f(z)$.

Let $E(z)=e^{-\alpha z}$. Then $(fE)'=0$ and so $fE=\beta$, a constant. Thus, $f(z)=\beta e^{\alpha z}$.

Finally, $|\alpha| = |f'(z)/f(z)| \le 1$.

Comment: and also the constant function satisfies the given condition will be of form $\beta e^{\alpha z}$ where $\alpha=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Obvously, the constant zero function is $\in F$, so henceforth assume $f\not\equiv 0$.
Let $z_0\in\Bbb C$. Then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ for some $n\ge 0$ and some entire $g(z)$ with $g(z_0)\ne 0$. This makes $$f'(z)=n(z-z_0)^{n-1}g(z)+(z-z_0)^ng'(z)$$
and so for $z\ne z_0$, $|f'(z)|\le |f(z)|$ amounts to
$$ |ng(z)+(z-z_0)g'(z)|\le |z-z_0||g(z)|$$
Take the limit as $z\to z_0$ to arrive at
$$ |ng(z_0)|\le 0,$$
in other words $n=0$, which means that $f(z_0)\ne 0$.

*Now* we can write $f(z)=e^{h(z)}$ for some entire $h$, obtain $f'(z)=h'(z)e^{h(z)}$, and by the given inequality $|h'(z)|\le 1$. The bounded entire function $h'$ must be constant, hence $h$ is of the form $h(z)=a+bz$.

Comment: " $f(z)=e^{h(z)}$ for some entire  $h$" .why so?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is not identically zero. Then $g=f'/f$ is meromorphic in the plane (that is, entire except for (isolated) poles.

But $g$ is bounded (on the set where $f\ne0$), and if a function is bounded near an isolated singularity the singularity is *removable*. So $g$ has no poles, hence  $f$ has no  zero.

So $f=e^L$ for some entire function $L$. Now $|f'|\le|f|$  shows that $|L'|\le1$. So $L'$ is constant. If $L'=c$ then $L(z)=cz+a,$so $$f(z)=e^ae^{cz}$$(and it's clear that $|c|\le1$).